# Не запускается Tomcat из Idea

Tags: intellij-idea, tomcat

Недавно начал получать при старте такое сообщение:
[image: Idea log]

Как с этим бороться? Пробовал вот эти темы:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20163910/tomcat-in-idea-war-exploded-server-is-not-connected-deploy-is-not-available
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25147843/server-is-not-connected-when-trying-to-deploy-with-intellij
но пока ничего не помогает (